# Why isn't "esnext.full" recognized as a valid "lib" option in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

When I'm specifying a `lib` option on my `compilerOptions`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext.full"]
}
```

VS Code gives a warning for `esnext.full`.  My understanding is that this should be valid, and should be roughly equivalent to specifying `esnext` along with `DOM` and `DOM.Iterable`.  How come VS Code doesn't recognize `esnext.full`?

Comment: "_My understanding is that this should be valid_": Why is that?

Comment: [The lib section of the TSConfig reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) enumerates the built-in library and individual component identifiers. It is the basis of the known options that the compiler will accept (apart from installing additional contributing packages).

Comment: @jsejcksn Because the [TypeScript source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/libs.json#L71) has them listed as 'default libraries'.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766948/why-isnt-esnext-full-recognized-as-a-valid-lib-option-in-vs-code?noredirect=1#comment133662590_75766948) I think that the meaning of "default" there is to signal which one will be used when changing the [`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target). If that answers your question, I can write it up as one. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah if you could write it as an answer, and explain why in that case it has the `.full` suffix.  Also, what list of `lib` do I need to specify to get the equivalent of the default (everything pulled in by something like `es2022.full`), but for `esnext` or `es2023`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't `"esnext.full"` recognized as a valid `"lib"` option in VS Code?

When searching for understanding, it's almost always more productive to seek the answer to questions when they're framed positively and skeptically (i.e. "What **does** exist?" / "Why **is** x valid?") — so, in this case: "Which values **can** be recognized?" Answering this question will provide knowledge about a restrictive scope, and a foundation for the rest of the answer.

The [`compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) section in the TSConfig reference enumerates the built-in library and individual component identifiers which are valid for inclusion in a [TSConfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) (at the string array property `compilerOptions.lib`).

I won't copy the entire list here — it's very large and subject to change.

The documentation itself recognizes the fact that the allowed values **do** change — by the inclusion of this footnote:

> This list may be out of date, you can see the full list in the [TypeScript source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/lib).

Presumably, the link pointed to a valid resource at one point in time, but as I write this answer, navigating to the resource results in a 404 response (Not Found). Perhaps the repo has been restructured since the documentation was last updated — the default branch currently does not have a top-level `lib` directory. However, by switching to a tag branch corresponding to a release (e.g. the [`v5.0.2` release](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v5.0.2) from a few days ago), the top-level `lib` directory can be viewed:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v5.0.2/lib

This is a directory of generated files (explained by the [readme](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.0.2/lib/README.md)) — generated from data in the corresponding source directory [`src/lib`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v5.0.2/src/lib).

So, up to this point, the best source for determining valid identifiers is "consult the documentation" — which, as we've seen, is not guaranteed to be up-to-date/exhaustive — and that's not even close to an acceptable answer in my opinion.

The documentation has to be derived from *something*, right?

Digging deeper into the source repo, we can find a module in the compiler code: [`src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.0.2/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L142-L241) which contains a const array of tuples named `libEntries`. Here's a partial snippet for reference:

```ts
const libEntries: [string, string][] = [

  // ---snip---

  ["es2023", "lib.es2023.d.ts"],
  ["esnext", "lib.esnext.d.ts"],
  // Host only
  ["dom", "lib.dom.d.ts"],
  ["dom.iterable", "lib.dom.iterable.d.ts"],

  // ---snip---

];
```

This is used as the basis for valid library identifiers, and is used to create the following exports:

```ts
/**
 * An array of supported "lib" reference file names used to determine the order for inclusion
 * when referenced, as well as for spelling suggestions. This ensures the correct ordering for
 * overload resolution when a type declared in one lib is extended by another.
 *
 * @internal
 */
export const libs = libEntries.map(entry => entry[0]);

/**
 * A map of lib names to lib files. This map is used both for parsing the "lib" command line
 * option as well as for resolving lib reference directives.
 *
 * @internal
 */
export const libMap = new Map(libEntries);
```

This is more satisfying. If you want an authoritative list of valid identifiers for use as `lib` values, that's the place to view them. Be sure to consult the tag branch corresponding to the compiler version that you're using.

---

So now back to your question:

> Why isn't `"esnext.full"` recognized as a valid `"lib"` option in VS Code?

The answer is now obviously simple: it's not recognized because it's not a valid identifier in the list.

This leads to your next question:

> Why is there a library file with the `.full` suffix?

As you observed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766948/why-isnt-esnext-full-recognized-as-a-valid-lib-option-in-vs-code?noredirect=1#comment133662590_75766948), TypeScript includes some [declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) files internally which cannot be used in the array of library names at [`compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) in a [TSConfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

You linked to [a JSON file in the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.0.2/src/lib/libs.json#L71) which lists some strings in an array at a `libs` key — these represent partial, relative path names to internal declaration files (see [`src/lib`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v5.0.2/src/lib)). However, this is not a list of allowed library identifiers — it is simply a list for internal use by the compiler.

At the end of that list is a grouping of "default libraries" separated by a comment:

```jsonc
{
  "libs": [

    // ---snip---

    // Default libraries
    "es5.full",
    "es2015.full",
    "es2016.full",
    "es2017.full",
    "es2018.full",
    "es2019.full",
    "es2020.full",
    "es2021.full",
    "es2022.full",
    "es2023.full",
    "esnext.full"
  ],

  // ---snip---
}
```

These values ending in the `.full` suffix refer to the internal declaration files which the compiler uses **by default** (in absence of a [`compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) array), according to the [`compilerOptions.target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) value:

> Changing `target` also changes the default value of [`lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib). You may “mix and match” `target` and `lib` settings as desired, but you could just set `target` for convenience.

Here's the utility function in the source which is used to derive the default library declaration file from the `target`:

[`src/compiler/utilitiesPublic.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.0.2/src/compiler/utilitiesPublic.ts#L295-L318):

```ts
export function getDefaultLibFileName(options: CompilerOptions): string {
    switch (getEmitScriptTarget(options)) {
        case ScriptTarget.ESNext:
            return "lib.esnext.full.d.ts";

        // ---snip---

        case ScriptTarget.ES2015:
            return "lib.es6.d.ts";  // We don't use lib.es2015.full.d.ts due to breaking change.
        default:
            return "lib.d.ts";
    }
}
```

---

Now, on to your final question:

> What list of `lib` do I need to specify to get the equivalent of the default (everything pulled in by something like `es2022.full`), but for `esnext` or `es2023`?

You listed two ECMAScript API collections — I'll use the first one you mentioned (`esnext`) as the example. However, note that it's not a real spec — it refers to *all "bleeding edge" features*:

> The special `ESNext` value refers to the highest version your version of TypeScript supports. This setting should be used with caution, since it doesn’t mean the same thing between different TypeScript versions and can make upgrades less predictable.

If you want to include the default libraries corresponding to `esnext` (`esnext.full`) in your compilation, here are two options for your TSConfig:

1. You can specify the libraries manually, along with your desired target:

   First, in the TypeScript repo:

   1. Navigate to the **tag branch** corresponding to the version of the compiler that you're using (in this example [`v5.0.2`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v5.0.2/lib)).
   2. Navigate to the top-level [`lib`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v5.0.2/lib) directory, and find the declaration file that corresponds to your target name and ends with `.full.d.ts` (in this case [`lib.esnext.full.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.0.2/lib/lib.esnext.full.d.ts)).

   After finding the corresponding declaration file, identify all of the libraries which are referenced by [triple-slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html). I'll inline the relevant content from the file linked above:

   ```ts
   /// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>

   /// <reference lib="esnext" />
   /// <reference lib="dom" />
   /// <reference lib="webworker.importscripts" />
   /// <reference lib="scripthost" />
   /// <reference lib="dom.iterable" />
   ```

   In your config:

   - Set [`compilerOptions.target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) to your desired target (for example, I'll use `"es2020"`), and
   - Set the [`compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) array to the libraries identified from the previous step above.

   This looks like:

   ```jsonc
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es2020",
       "lib": [
         "esnext",
         "dom",
         "webworker.importscripts",
         "scripthost",
         "dom.iterable",
       ],

       // ---snip---
     },

     // ---snip---
   }
   ```

   By the way, these compiler options values are not case-sensitive.
2. More conveniently (if you're ok with whatever the current default behavior might be), you can let the compiler use the defaults according to your compilation target by omitting the `compilerOptions.lib` array:

   - Set [`compilerOptions.target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) to your target (in this case `"esnext"`), and
   - Don't define the [`compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) property at all.

   This looks like:

   ```jsonc
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "esnext",

       // ---snip---
     },

     // ---snip---
   }
   ```

   This will use the default libraries for your target (the internal `esnext.full` declaration file).

---

Finally, an observation: If you're targeting a normal browser environment, you likely **don't** want `"webworker.importscripts"` and `"scripthost"` which aren't part of that environment, but **are** included in the defaults. A more appropriate choice in that case might be `["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"]`.

This isn't an answer about compilation philosophy or best practice, but it's safer to compile to a single target environment for each compilation, and to restrict the included libraries to *only* what's available in that one target environment — this helps prevent using APIs that don't exist in the target environment and would cause runtime exceptions.

---

That was a bit of a journey, but I hope you now have greater confidence and better understanding of how library inclusion is handled during compilation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very useful.  One thing - you say webworker.importscripts isn't available in a web browser environment.  Aren't web workers available in browsers?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766948/why-isnt-esnext-full-recognized-as-a-valid-lib-option-in-vs-code/75782069?noredirect=1#comment133682469_75782069) @Jez Yes, but the web worker global context is different than the window global context: some APIs are common, while each has some exclusive APIs. I think that worker scripts should be compiled separately from window scripts — each using their own corresponding library types.